# Parsec optionMaybe always consuming input

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to debug why despite combining `optionMaybe` with `try`, parsec is consuming the input. Basically in the below code, why is the second run not returning `Right "abc"` (which is what I expect)?

Given

```
myParser = do
    optionMaybe $ try (between (char '/') (char '/') $ many1 (noneOf "/")
    many1 (noneOf "/")
```

I get

```
> parse myParser "" "/abc/def"
Right "def"

> parse myParser "" "/abc"
Left (line 1, column 5):
unexpected end of input
expecting "/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole of `between (char '/') (char '/') $ many1 (noneOf "/")` fails due to the missing closing `'/'` in `"/abc"` , and so `optionMaybe $ try $ between ...` doesn't consume anything (and results in `Nothing`). You're left with all of `"/abc"` of the input, which of course doesn't match the remaining parser `many1 (noneOf "/")`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized it myself. A silly mistake! Thanks.